# Best way to output a very simple menu in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and my question is *extremely* simple. I want to just know the *best* way to output a navigation menu on a page (i.e. literally just page links).

So my main app.js has this code:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import NavMenu from "./nav-menu";

const theLinks = [
  "home",
  "subs"
]

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      navLinks: theLinks
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="container">
        <NavMenu navLinks={this.state.navLinks} />
      </div>
    );
  } 
}
```

And the nav-menu component has this code:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

export default class navBar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      this.props.navLinks.map((c, i) => <a href={c[1]} key = {i} > {c[0]} </a>)
    )
  }
}
```

Which *should* (but doesn't) output is like this:

```
<div id="container"><a href="/index"> home </a><a href="/subs"> subs </a></div>
```

Why is this not outputting like the above? My gut feeling also senses that this is not a good way to output a menu or list of links. What is a better way?

Thanks for any advice here. I'm trying to learn react pragmatically and without having to study a long course.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hunbng?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: Your navlinks are defined as an array containing an object with a dynamic key and value, your `c[0]` is not what you expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array has quite a strange structure. I'd go for something more readable/usable:

App.js

```js
import React, {Component} from "react";
import NavMenu from "./nav-menu";

const theLinks = [
  {
    name: "home",
    href: "/index"
  },
  {
    name: "subs",
    href: "/subs"
  },
]

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      navLinks: theLinks
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="container">
        <NavMenu navLinks={this.state.navLinks} />
      </div>
    );
  } 
}
```

nav-menu.js

```js
import React, {Component} from "react";

export default class navBar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      // it's considered bad practice to use the map-index as a key, hence the href as key
      this.props.navLinks.map((c) => <a href={c.href} key={c.href} > {c.name} </a>)
    )
  }
}
```